# Checkbox with multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox

Trying to set up checkboxes for a form so that users can select multiple values:

```
<%= f.label :sport %>
<%= f.check_box_tag (:sport,{ :multiple => true }, Football, Basketball, Volleyball, Lacrosse, nil) %>
```

I'm getting a syntax error: `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'`

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a space between `check_box_tag` and its arguments. Delete that space...the left parenthesis should be right against the method name:

```
<%= f.check_box_tag(:sport,{ :multiple => true }, Football, Basketball, Volleyball, Lacrosse, nil) %>
```

With the space, Ruby parses it differently, as a method call where the first argument is a parenthesized expression. Then, when parsing the expression, it is not expecting a comma.